# Multiple clocks using java GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I am doing a project in which i have to create a set of 6 clocks showing different times for different places using java GUI. I have successfully created the code for showing one clock using threading. But how to create 6 different threads to handle the 6 clocks?
This is the following class which creates a single clock:

```
public class analogClockGUI extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    int secx,secy,lsecx,lsecy;               
    int minx,miny,lminx,lminy;          
    int hrx,hry,lhrx,lhry;
    int secRadius,minRadius,hrRadius,center;
    int pointx1,pointy1,pointx2,pointy2;

    double dhs,dhm,dhh;        
    Random rndm;               
    Thread t;
    Font clockFont;
    Date incre;
    int s,h,m;

    boolean off=false,drawFirst=true;
    Dimension dimension;
    Color wallColor,backColor=Color.black;

    int previousMin,previousSec;
    int change;    

    public analogClockGUI()
    {

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me)
            {
                dimension=getSize();


                if(change!=dimension.height)
                {
                    center=dimension.height/2;
                    setSize(new Dimension(dimension.height,dimension.height));
                }
                /*else
                {
                    center=dimension.width/2;
                    setSize(new Dimension(dimension.width,dimension.width));
                }*/
                drawFirst=true;
                change=dimension.height;     
                secRadius=(int)(0.7*center);
                minRadius=(int)(0.75*center);
                hrRadius=(int)(0.5*center);

            }
        });
        init();
    }



    public void init()
    {

        rndm=new Random();
        t=new Thread(this);
        dimension=getSize();
        center=dimension.height/2;

        secRadius=(int)(0.7*center);   
        minRadius=(int)(0.75*center);
        hrRadius=(int)(0.5*center);
        wallColor=new Color(rndm.nextInt(255),rndm.nextInt(255),rndm.nextInt(255));
        t.start();
    }
    public void run() throws NullPointerException
    {
        while(true)
        {
            s=new Date().getSeconds();//+incre.getSeconds(); 

            if(s!=previousSec)
            {

                dhs=Math.toRadians(s*6-90);
                secx=(int)(secRadius*Math.cos(dhs))+center;
                secy=(int)(secRadius*Math.sin(dhs))+center;

                pointx1=(int)((secRadius+center*0.15)*Math.cos(dhs))+center;
                pointy1=(int)((secRadius+center*0.15)*Math.sin(dhs))+center;


                m=new Date().getMinutes();
                dhm=Math.toRadians(m*6-90);
                minx=(int)(minRadius*Math.cos(dhm))+center;
                miny=(int)(minRadius*Math.sin(dhm))+center;

                pointx2=(int)((secRadius+center*0.15)*Math.cos(dhm))+center;
                pointy2=(int)((secRadius+center*0.15)*Math.sin(dhm))+center;


                h =new Date().getHours();
                dhh=Math.toRadians(h*30-90+((m-1)/2));
                hrx=(int)(hrRadius*Math.cos(dhh))+center;
                hry=(int)(hrRadius*Math.sin(dhh))+center;

                repaint();
                previousSec=s;
            }
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                if(off)
                    break;
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}          
        }
    }
    public void upgate(Graphics g) throws NullPointerException
    {

        if(drawFirst==true)
        {

            clockFont=new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,(int)(0.2*center));
            drawFirst=false;
        }
        if(m!=previousMin){
            if(s==0)
            {

                wallColor=new Color(rndm.nextInt(255),rndm.nextInt(255),rndm.nextInt(255));
                g.setColor(wallColor);
                g.fillOval(0,0,2*center,2*center);
                g.setColor(backColor);
                g.fillOval((int)(0.1*center),(int)(0.1*center),(int)(center*1.8),(int)(center*1.8));

                clear(g);
                previousMin=m;
            }}
        drawPoints(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(clockFont);

        g.drawString("12",(int)(0.9*center),(int)(0.25*center));
        g.drawString("6",(int)(0.95*center),(int)(1.885*center));
        g.drawString("9",(int)(0.11*center),(int)(1.06*center));
        g.drawString("3",(int)(1.805*center),(int)(1.07*center));
        g.drawString("1",(int)(1.369*center),(int)(0.36*center));
        g.drawString("2",(int)(1.674*center),(int)(0.645*center));
        g.drawString("4",(int)(1.665*center),(int)(1.485*center));
        g.drawString("5",(int)(1.372*center),(int)(1.778*center));
        g.drawString("7",(int)(0.545*center),(int)(1.777*center));
        g.drawString("8",(int)(0.227*center),(int)(1.485*center));
        g.drawString("10",(int)(0.212*center),(int)(0.675*center));
        g.drawString("11",(int)(0.522*center),(int)(0.365*center));


        if(lsecx!=0)
        {
            g.setColor(backColor);
            g.drawLine(center,center,lsecx,lsecy);

        }


        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawLine(center,center,hrx,hry);
        g.drawLine(center+1,center,hrx,hry);
        g.drawLine(center-1,center,hrx,hry);
        g.drawLine(center,center+1,hrx,hry);
        g.drawLine(center,center-1,hrx,hry);
        g.drawLine(center+2,center,hrx,hry);
        g.drawLine(center-2,center,hrx,hry);
        g.drawLine(center,center+2,hrx,hry);
        g.drawLine(center,center-2,hrx,hry);

        //show the minute hand with bigger size
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(center,center,minx,miny);
        g.drawLine(center+1,center,minx,miny);
        g.drawLine(center-1,center,minx,miny);
        g.drawLine(center,center+1,minx,miny);
        g.drawLine(center,center-1,minx,miny);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(center,center,secx,secy);
        g.fillOval(center-3,center-3,6,6);       //center point

        if(m%5!=0)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.fillOval(pointx2-2,pointy2-2,4,4);

        }

        if(s%5!=0)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(pointx1-2,pointy1-2,4,4);

        }

        lminx=minx;
        lminy=miny;
        lhrx=hrx;
        lhry=hry;
        lsecx=secx;
        lsecy=secy;



    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)  throws NullPointerException
    {
        g.setColor(wallColor);
        g.fillOval(0,0,2*center,2*center);
        g.setColor(backColor);
        g.fillOval((int)(0.1*center),(int)(0.1*center),(int)(center*1.8),(int)(center*1.8));
        upgate(g);
    }
    public void clear(Graphics g)  throws NullPointerException
    {
        if(lsecx!=0)
        {
            g.setColor(backColor);
            g.drawLine(center,center,lhrx,lhry);
            g.drawLine(center+1,center,lhrx,lhry);
            g.drawLine(center-1,center,lhrx,lhry);
            g.drawLine(center,center+1,lhrx,lhry);
            g.drawLine(center,center-1,lhrx,lhry);
            g.drawLine(center+2,center,lhrx,lhry);
            g.drawLine(center-2,center,lhrx,lhry);
            g.drawLine(center,center+2,lhrx,lhry);
            g.drawLine(center,center-2,lhrx,lhry);

            g.drawLine(center,center,lminx,lminy);
            g.drawLine(center+1,center,lminx,lminy);
            g.drawLine(center-1,center,lminx,lminy);
            g.drawLine(center,center+1,lminx,lminy);
            g.drawLine(center,center-1,lminx,lminy);


        }


    }
    public void drawPoints(Graphics g) throws NullPointerException
    {
        int x1,y1;
        double p;
        for(int i=1;i<=60;i++)
        {
            if(i%5!=0)
            {
                p=i*0.10472;
                x1=(int)((secRadius+center*0.15)*Math.cos(p))+center;
                y1=(int)((secRadius+center*0.15)*Math.sin(p))+center;
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
                g.fillOval(x1-2,y1-2,4,4);

            }
        }


    }
    public void stop() throws NullPointerException /*close the thread when applet stopped*/
    {
        off=true;
        t=null;
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you displaying the first clock? Threading sounds overcomplicated for the task of just showing multiple clocks. For example, if you instead had six text boxes in your GUI, you wouldn't start a separate thread for each of them.

Comment: Now, when i try to change the size of one clock object, the other clock objects also displays the changed clock object.

Comment: Oh sorry, i now edited, the code. The hands should move now.

Comment: Why don't you use `Timer`, it's much easier to implement, and in fact, I can't see why one clock should affect the other?

Comment: In my main method, i am making six objects of class AnalogClockGUI and added this six objects to six different frames. Now after running the code when i try changing the frame size using my mouse, the other frames displays the clock of every other frames.

Comment: I don't know how to use Timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem is in your `Thread#run` code...Every instance of you clock is using the same `Date` value.

```
public void run() throws NullPointerException {
    while (true) {
        // !! This is wrong !!
        // Each clock should have its own concept of it's start time, then each "second" you
        // should advance the time by a single second...
        s = new Date().getSeconds();//+incre.getSeconds();
```

The other problem you have is that you shouldn't be modifying the values that the UI relies on within the content of the thread...

```
        // This is a bad idea...
        if (s != previousSec) {

            dhs = Math.toRadians(s * 6 - 90);
            secx = (int) (secRadius * Math.cos(dhs)) + center;
            secy = (int) (secRadius * Math.sin(dhs)) + center;

            pointx1 = (int) ((secRadius + center * 0.15) * Math.cos(dhs)) + center;
            pointy1 = (int) ((secRadius + center * 0.15) * Math.sin(dhs)) + center;


            m = new Date().getMinutes();
            dhm = Math.toRadians(m * 6 - 90);
            minx = (int) (minRadius * Math.cos(dhm)) + center;
            miny = (int) (minRadius * Math.sin(dhm)) + center;

            pointx2 = (int) ((secRadius + center * 0.15) * Math.cos(dhm)) + center;
            pointy2 = (int) ((secRadius + center * 0.15) * Math.sin(dhm)) + center;


            h = new Date().getHours();
            dhh = Math.toRadians(h * 30 - 90 + ((m - 1) / 2));
            hrx = (int) (hrRadius * Math.cos(dhh)) + center;
            hry = (int) (hrRadius * Math.sin(dhh)) + center;

            repaint();
            previousSec = s;
        }
```

The problem is, the UI could be updated, before all the values are updated, causing strange and unpredictable paint artifices.

And do you really need a 100 milisecond update??  I would be better to scale out the sleep to 500 milliseconds, putting either slight early or slight late behind the second change.

You painting also freaks me out.  Be VERY careful, `JPanel` already has a method called `update(Graphics)` inherited from `Container`, you could end up with a naming conflict that would crash your program (as `update` is used by the repaint engine`)

Very rarely should you need to override `paint` directly, it is preferred that you use `paintComponent`.  This ensures that the component is updated and prepared properly on each paint cycle.  As part of the process, `paintComponent` will also clear the graphics context, so there should be no need for the `clear` method (so long as you honoring the paint chain and calling `super.paintComponent`

**Ideas and solutions**

What I would do, is set up a "ticker" class, whose sole responsibility is to notify registered classes that a "tick" has occurred.  In this class, I would use a `javax.swing.Timer`.  This would force "tick" events to be called from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, ensuring that changes to the variables that the paint methods rely on are updated within the context of the same thread.  I might consider using a delay of something like 250 milliseconds, allowing for some extra fudge in the notification cycle.

Regardless of whether use or a `Thread` or `Timer`, you're going to end up with a bottle neck as you update the "ticks".

I would also consider painting the face of the clock to a `BufferedImage`, as it's not likely to change unless the size of the component changes.  This will make the paints quicker.

Comment: After changing paint to paintComponent, it is working fine. Thanking you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As these clocks only differ by the fixed time offsets, they probably do not require individual threads or even individual timer tasks. Write a larger, more complex `paintComponent` method to draw multiple clocks with different time offsets that are using the same base time value.

Comment: +1, yes, that's the way I would do it.  A clock component that takes a time-offset, (and probably position and parent), as ctor params.  Create as many as needed, store in vector and fire in wall-time to some 'timeUpdate' method on each periodically.